# Use variable with quotes with system in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have

myVar.value = 123521@machine OK

now I'm using this variable with system command as it's an argument passed to a binary .exe

so I have to add quotes to myVar.value as it caontains spaces
I tried :
'''myVar.value''' but this will give 'myVar.value', whereas I just want to have the result equal to "123521@machine OK"

how could I use the quotes in this case ?

Comment: Please provide the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = ['"' myVar.value '"']
```

I think you can use double quote characters within strings demarcated by single quotes. Within a string demarcated by single quotes characters by doubling up:

```
x = ['''' myVar.value '''']
```